# Can I make the falling sand game run parallel on the GPU?

Tags: gpu, simulation, metal

I've been trying to put together a falling sand type game in Metal, that uses a compute shader to do the work. My initial work looked ok, until I ran into the following problem:

[image: Sand particles]

In one update, both particle 1A and 1B could flow into space T.

**Sequential**

In a sequential loop, I could understand how I would simply move 1A into T, then when it came to evaluate 1B, I could see that the space was already filled.

**Parallel**

My problem is that with the GPU, The code to check 1A and 1B are both running on different threads, so in one update loop, they can both move to position T, essentially killing one of them.

My question is then, can I make a parallel solution to this, or can it only be solved sequentially?

Here's my calculation code, running a GPU thread for every pixel in a 640 by 480 grid:

```
struct Particle {
    float4 color;
    int live;
    int particleType;
};


kernel void calculateFrame(
                           device Particle *src [[buffer(1)]],
                           device Particle *dst [[buffer(2)]],
                           uint2 threadgroup_position_in_grid   [[ threadgroup_position_in_grid ]],
                           uint2 thread_position_in_threadgroup [[ thread_position_in_threadgroup ]],
                           uint2 threads_per_threadgroup        [[ threads_per_threadgroup ]]) {

    uint2 gid = threadgroup_position_in_grid;
    int index = (gid * 640) + gid;
    Particle particle = src[index];

    Particle bottom = src[toLinear( gid + uint2( 0, 1))]; //bottom
    Particle bottomLeft = src[toLinear( gid + uint2(-1, 1))]; //bottom left
    Particle bottomRight = src[toLinear( gid + uint2( 1, 1))]; //bottom right

    if (particle.live == 1 && particle.particleType == SAND) { // move down

        if (bottom.live == 0) {

            dst[index].live = 0;

            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( 0, 1))].particleType = particle.particleType;
            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( 0, 1))].color = particle.color;
            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( 0, 1))].live = 1;

        }
        else if (bottomLeft.live == 0) { // move down to the left if clear
            dst[index].live = 0;

            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( -1, 1))].particleType = particle.particleType;
            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( -1, 1))].color = red;
            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( -1, 1))].live = 1;


        }
        else if (bottomRight.live == 0) { // move down to the right if clear

            dst[index].live = 0;

            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( 1, 1))].particleType = particle.particleType;
            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( 1, 1))].color = red;
            dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( 1, 1))].live = 1;
        }
        else { // cant move
            dst[index] = src[index];
        }

    }

    if (particle.particleType == WALL) {
        dst[index] = particle;
        dst[index].live = 1;
    }

    if (particle.particleType == ERASER) {
        dst[index].color = blue;
        dst[index].live = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "code" is confusing because there are unexplained undeclared variables, like `reverse` and `particleRef`. That said, the general solution to this type of problem is atomic compare-and-exchange. Each thread says "if the value is how I expect it to be, then change it to this other value". Only one thread "wins". There will have to be some fallback logic that the losing thread does, instead.

Comment: Sorry @KenThomases I had some atomic code in there that I was trying, I've cleaned it up now.

Comment: I guess I need to investigate how to do an atomic compare and exchange in this scenario.

Comment: Does the `dst` buffer start with undefined contents? Or is it initially a copy of `src`? Or perhaps cleared out? Does `src` need to remain unmodified?

Comment: The `dst` buffer is cleared every frame. `src` can be modified as `dst` is the `src` of the next frame.

Comment: Then you can use logic like "if (bottom.live == 0 && I win the atomic compare dst[toLinear( gid + uint2( 0, 1))].live to 0 and exchange with 1) …".